# If $\beta_{k}=\beta_{n}+\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}\alpha_{i}$ for all $n>k$, then $\beta_{n}\to0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I constructed two sequences $(\alpha_{k})$ and $(\beta_{k})$ in $[0,\infty)$ that satisfy $$\beta_{k}=\beta_{n}+\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}\alpha_{i}$$ for all $n>k$. Can I conclude from this that $\beta_{n}\to0$? My intuition says yes, but I don't know how to prove it. In particular, the property implies that $$\beta_{k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\beta_{n}+\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}\alpha_{i}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $n > k$, then:

$$\beta_k=\beta_{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \alpha_i = \beta_{n+2} + \sum_{i=2}^{n+1} \alpha_i=\beta_{k+1}$$

So we can prove by induction, that $\beta_i = \beta_{i+1}$.

Edit: this doesn't mean, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \beta_n = 0$, just take $\beta_i = 1$ and $\alpha = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think that you anwered before my edit, so I'm sorry for that. Inspired by your approach, I think I am able to prove that $$\beta_{n+N}-\beta_{n}=\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+N}\alpha_{i}$$ for all $n>k$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$, but I still dont see if $\beta_{n}\to0$ or not.

Comment: Because it doesn't have to be, just place $\beta_i = 1$ and $\alpha_i = 0$. The equality holds and $\beta_i \to 1$